# Is This A New Edit Feature?

Tags: discussion

With regards to this question entitled [Change Dock color on left/right site in OS X 10.9 Mavericks.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106331/change-dock-color-on-left-right-site-in-os-x-10-9-mavericks)

I came across this edit which I ve never seen before:

[image]

Is it new or just the fact it is not used very often ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not new, it just a quoted section starting with `>`. You can see for yourself how it's done by just clicking on `edit` and having a look at the raw text.

If you want to see all the formatting options/commands, you can either click on the blue question mark at top right of any edit windows or look at the [Markdown Editing Help](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Comment: Thats fine. I've never seen it before, and wasn't really sure what it was trying to infer ?

Comment: It's just a block quote basically

Comment: Thought I would ask anyway :)